# Christoffel symbols calculation

Tags: differential-geometry

> Calculate the Christoffel symbols of the surface parameterized by $f(u,v) = (u\cos v , u\sin v, u)$ by using the defintion of Christoffel symbols.

If I am going to use the definition to calculate the Christoffel symbols $(\Gamma^i_{jk})$ then I need to use the coefficents that express the vectors $f_{uu}, f_{uv},$ and $f_{vv}$ in terms of the tangent vectors $f_u$ and $f_v$ and the normal vector $N$.

Thus:

$$f_{u_1u_1} = \Gamma^1_{11} f_{u_1} + \Gamma^2_{11}f_{u_2} + A \vec{N}$$
$$f_{u_1u_2} = f_{u_2u_1} = \Gamma^1_{12} f_{u_1} + \Gamma^2_{12}f_{u_2} + B \vec{N}$$
$$f_{u_2u_2} = \Gamma^1_{22} f_{u_1} + \Gamma^2_{22}f_{u_2} + C\vec{N}$$

$f_u = (\cos v, \sin v, 1),$
$f_v = (-u\sin v, u\cos v, 0),$
$f_{uu} = (0,0,0),$
$f_{vv} = (-u\cos v, -u \sin v, 0),$
$f_{uv} = (-\sin v, \cos v,0).$

How can I calculate the Christoffel symbols from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a general procedure to find all these Christoffel symbols:

First of all, take dot product $f_{u_1}$ to the first equation

$$(1)\ \ \ f_{u_1 u_1} \cdot f_{u_1} = \Gamma_{11}^1 f_{u_1} \cdot f_{u_1} + \Gamma_{11}^2 f_{u_2} \cdot f_{u_1}$$

Similarly, take dot product $f_{u_2}$ to the first equation, you get

$$(2)\ \ \ f_{u_1 u_1} \cdot f_{u_2} = \Gamma_{11}^1 f_{u_1} \cdot f_{u_2} + \Gamma_{11}^2 f_{u_2} \cdot f_{u_2}$$

the normal $N$ do not appear as $N\cdot f_{u_1} = N\cdot f_{u_2} = 0$. (1) and (2) forms a system of two linear equations with two unknown $\Gamma_{11}^1$ and $\Gamma_{11}^2$. The matrix is just the first fundamental form, thus is invertible. Hence $\Gamma_{11}^1$ and $\Gamma_{11}^2$ can be found. The same procedure applied to the second and third equation will help you find all the Christoffel symbols.

Indeed, you have $f_{u_1} \cdot f_{u_2} = 0$, so the equation can be solved very easily.

Comment: If I take the dot product then $f_u \dot\ f_v = 0$. But why do we have to get rid of $N$?

Comment: I mean take dot product $f_u$ to the first equation, and then take dot product to the first equation (so you form two equations). If you have $f_u \cdot f_v$, this is just easier.

Comment: I am not following?

Comment: @Lays: I have edited the answer. Please check if it is okay.

Comment: Yes, it is much more clear. Thank you very much!